# Can I reapply immediately after a UK visa refusal?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

I applied for a UK visitor visa in 2013 and I was refused because I did not explain the funds in my account. Now, in May 2017, I applied again and was refused again.

[image]

Can I reapply immediately? What do I need to provide to demonstrate a change in my circumstances? How do I explain how that the  money is from my sponsor, since I am a student and I choose to take care of the travel expenses myself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60918/discussion-on-question-by-violet-andrew-can-i-reapply-immediately-after-a-uk-vis).